# Android OpenGL ES and size of app

Tags: android, opengl-es

i am studying android development and i cannot run an Open g l ES 1.0 in emulator although i had call set E G L Config function. i can run it in my device but it not like an example i had run. in my code i has copied it from an example. When i run it, it perform 1 triangle longer than triangle in the example. And when i installed it in my device, only Hello World app has 3,5 MB in the memory, but the example only has 50 KB. Why?

Comment: Are you referring to the size of the APK file? Or the memory usage of the app?

Comment: i has downloaded an example and when i installed it in my device and use my device to view the APK file i see it takes 16 KB while my Hello app takes 3,52 MB. i meant the size of APK file

Comment: @samgak can you help me? My Android emulator cannot run any OpenGL ES app although in the past it can. How i should config it?